# When to use Multi-Output / Single-Output Gaussian Processes

Tags: gaussian-process

Suppose I have an input data set of dimensionality D, which computes M output variables using some black-box-calculation (in my case an FE simulation model). I know that these output variables are correlated, so modeling them in a multi-output Gaussian process would be helpful. My question is: if my Gaussian process should predict values for an output, only the input parameters would be available, but not the other outputs correlated with the output to be predicted. Can such a prediction work at all and how useful would it be?

Comment: Perhaps you can give an example of what you are looking for. I'm not sure it's totally clear from the question by itself.